# PHP header0 failing inside $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET'

Tags: php, http-headers

I am trying to return json data from a php script. The data is formatted as json and I am setting the header "Content-Type: application/json".  This works fine until I put my header() call inside of an if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET'){ block

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') {
   header("Content-Type: application/json");
   echo '{"name":"Larry","town":"Pungaville"}';
}
```

The problem is that the Content-Type header falls back to text/html, **perhaps indicating that there is some output happening before I call header(). - but where?**

Now it gets weird, when I change the if-statement to (1==1).  The header is set correctly as application/json.  This is not simply a case of the 'if' failing as the data is still output either time.

```
<?php

if (1==1){
   header("Content-Type: application/json");
   echo '{"name":"Larry","town":"Pungaville"}';
}
```

What is happening?
How can ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') be causing output?
There is nothing else inside the php files besides what is shown here.
I am testing the returned headers with curl and viewing the payload in Firefox.

I am using php8.1 with nginx 1.18.0 on Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: why not call `header("Content-Type: application/json");` at the start of the script if you wanna return json all the time?

Comment: Check your log for a "Headers already sent" warning and fix the problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php